# A convex function $f$ is strictly convex $\iff$ $\nabla f$ is injective

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

If we consider a $\mathcal C^1$ function $f:\mathbb R^d\rightarrow \mathbb R$ that is convex, is it true that $f$ is strictly convex $\iff$ $\nabla f$ is injective?

This result is clearly true for $d=1$ since strict convexity is equivalent to having a strictly increasing hence injective derivative. Therefore, does this one-dimensional property generalize to a function of $\mathbb R^d$?

Answer (score 2):

Consider $g(t)=f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2).$ Then $g$ is strictly convex on $[0,1 ]$ like $f$. As a consequence, from the one dimensional case.  $g'(0)=(x_1-x_2)^Tf'(x_2)<g'(1)=(x_1-x_2)^Tf'(x_1)$, which implies $f'(x_1)\neq f'(x_2).$

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is not strictly convex, then there would exist $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for all $t\in[0,1]$,
$$
(1-t)f(x) + tf(y) = f((1-t)x+ty).
$$
Differentiating with respect to $t$ yields,
$$
f(y) - f(x) = \nabla f((1-t)x+ty)\cdot (y-x)
$$
for all $t\in [0,1]$. Namely, $f(y) = f(x) +\nabla f(x)\cdot (y-x)$. As $f\in C^1$ and convex, $\ell(z) = f(x) +\nabla f(x)\cdot (z-x)$ is the unique supporting hyperplane at $x$. As $(y, f(y))$ is contained on this hyperplane, then this is also the unique supporting hyperplane at $y$, i.e. $\nabla f(x) = \nabla f(y)$. Therefore $\nabla f$ is not injective.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why would the first equality be true for all $t\in[0,1]$ and not just for one such $t$?

Comment: Think of it graphically. A strictly convex function is a convex function whose graph contains no line segments. Thus if $f$ is convex but not strictly convex function, the graph must contain a line segment somewhere.

Comment: Graphically it does make lots of sense, but is there a way of proving this fact rigorously?

Comment: First you fix $x,y$ and $t_0$ such that $f((1-t_0)x+t_0y) = (1-t_0)f(x) + t_0f(y)$. From here you can change this to the single variable case by letting $g(t) = f((1-t)x+ty$ so that the previous equality becomes $g(t_0) = (1-t_0)g(0) + t_0g(1)$. The rest follows from noting that the slopes of a convex function are increasing. If $g(t)<(1-t)g(0) + tg(1)$, and $t\in(0,t_0)$ then the slope from $t_0$ to $t$ will be greater than the slope from $t_0$ to $1$, which implies the slope is decreasing. Similarly if $t\in (t_0,1)$. Try and finish the proof from here, but it is 1-dimensional now so easier.

Comment: The point is once this is in one dimension you can use basic properties of lines and slopes. Use pictures to convince yourself and then do the algebra. If I have time later I will come back and fill in the details myself, but my wife is 40 weeks pregnant so no telling when I will have time!

Comment: Your property of $C^1$ convex function is not true. In fact, $v$ could be $\nabla f((x)$ plus anything which is perpendicular to $y - x$.

Comment: You are correct, that statement is true only when the inequality holds for all $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$. I was just trying to use the uniqueness of the supporting hyperplane. I have updated my proof, let me know if you see any other issues.